# Algorithm for finding largest square divisor

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, number-theory

Given a positive integer n, find largest integer a such that a*a divides n.

If you know the factorization of n, it's fairly trivial. The question is, can it be done asymptotically faster than factoring n using the best known method? Is there any polynomial algorithm? (polynomial in bit-length of n)

For example with Pollard's rho algorithm for factorization it would run in O(n^(1/4)), but I'm looking for better.

Comment: Factorization takes O(sqrt(n)). Are you looking for a solution faster than that?

Comment: You can do it in O(n^(1/3)) instead of O(n^(1/2))

Comment: Fastest known factorization algorithm, General number field sieve, is much faster than that, and I am curious if this can be done even faster. I meant polynomial in bit-length of n, I should probably clarify that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not true!  Stopping at the 4th root of 125 would miss 5^2.

Comment: I already know how to solve this in O(n^(1/4)) I should probably include that in the question

Comment: @JánPriner Does your solution cover the case of `p * q * q` where `p <= q` and close in size?

Comment: @btilly yes, if you know the factorization n=p1^a1*p2^a2*...*pn^an, all you need to do is to compute p1^[a1/2]*p2^[a2/2]*...*pn^[an/2] (where [x] is floor of x)

Comment: @btilly OP cited algorithm complexity of **O(n^0.25)** to factor an integer -- not stopping the factor search at that value.  Once you factor the number, finding the desired solution is linear on the quantity of unique prime factors.

Comment: are basic operations considered `O(1)` or not (you know if you got bignums it might change the obvious complexities a lot)? using quadratic sieve is fastest approach I know of for bignums as it does not need multiplication at all (if you realize you are incrementing the quadrated variable)  however on atomic numbers you might get faster ...

Comment: @Spektre I don't consider basic operation to be O(1), although I don't think it would change much. If there is a polynomial algorithm, it would be polynomial regardless of whether basic operations are considered O(1) or not.

Comment: You don't need to get all the prime factors, but only those, the square of which has a chance to divide n. In practice, this means that you only have to consider the prime divisors less or equal to n^0.25, plus n^0.5.  It is not clear for me if it is something you already have considered

Comment: @JánPriner that changes things a lot as some algorithms use just `O(n)` operations like (`+,-,&,|,^`,...)  and others are using more complex one like multiplication division ... so even if you got faster complexity on atomic O(1) operations you might end up with far worse polynomial complexity on bignums ... That is why I asked ....

Comment: @damien: the number might be *p²q*, where *p* and *q* are close to the cube root. Or it could even be p³, in which case the largest square factor is still p².

Comment: @rici. You are right. Good eye

Comment: In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) it says: "No algorithm is known for computing any of these square-free factors, which is faster than computing the complete prime factorization. In particular, there is no known polynomial-time algorithm for computing the square-free part of an integer, and no known polynomial-time algorithm for determining whether a number is square-free"

Comment: @juvian Thanks for pointing this out, that's actually answers my question (sort of).

Comment: In contrast to that, finding the greatest square divisor of a polynomial is fairly simple using derivation and Euklid's algorithm.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2239/14578

Comment: juvian, please convert your comment into an answer. It is the correct answer for the question.